# Discord.js : Trying to export client from ./index.js, but it keeps saying client is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord bot using node.js, I wanted to create a command that sends a dm to a certain user, but I can't get my client variable into the needed file.

Here's my code in index.js

```
// my index.js file
client.login(token)
module.exports = client;

// my sendMessage.js file
const bot = require("../index");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('new-command')
        .setDescription('some description'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // interaction.guild is the object representing the Guild in which the command was run
        bot.users.cache.get('439484647022526465').send("test");
    }
};
```

Comment: You would need to provide exact error message - I don't understand what's undefined...

Comment: You can use `interaction.client` to get the client.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tetie said, use `interaction.client` in your `execute` function instead of export/importing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `client` object is a named export.

Try importing it this way:

```
const {client} = require("../index");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('new-command')
        .setDescription('some description'),
    async execute(interaction) {
// the object name changes here
        client.users.cache.get('439484647022526465').send("test");
    }
};
```